# Get subdirectories

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to list all subdirectories in a directory. I wan't to show only the Name of the directory. For example "Program Files" not "C:\Program Files".

This will not work for me, because it returns full paths.

```
Dim Dirs As String() = IO.Directory.GetDirectories("C:\")
```

I tried using:

```
Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo(Path)
Dim Drs As IO.DirectoryInfo = di.GetDirectories()
```

But it returns an error. What should I use instead?

Comment: Sorry, I just found the answer! Here it is:

       Dim di As New DirectoryInfo("C:\Test")
       For Each subdi As DirectoryInfo In di.GetDirectories
          MsgBox(subdi.Name)
       Next

Comment: Don't be sorry.  It's always good to be able to answer your own question!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are getting an error because you need to store in array type:

```
Dim Drs() As IO.DirectoryInfo = di.GetDirectories()
```

You can list the directory names only using the `DirectoryInfo.Name` property:

```
For Each dr As IO.DirectoryInfo In drs
    Console.WriteLine(dr.Name)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Your [`DirectoryInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx) instances (`Drs`) has a [`Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.name.aspx) property. That contains the name of the directory without the full path.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't compile.  You should instead use:

```
Dim Drs() As IO.DirectoryInfo = di.GetDirectories()
```

`di.GetDirectories()` returns an array of DirectoryInfo - as, of course, you're getting directories, not a single directory.