# VB.NET Iteration and folder operations

Tags: vb.net

I am new to VB. Can anyone help on this, thanks. BTW, it's bloody pain to mess the formatting here :) How to do the indent?

parameters:

- source file
- target
- backup folder

**Pseudocode:**

```
get all sub folders under target  

for each folder under target   
    if exists source file   
       if exists backup folder 
          replace/copy source file to backup folder  
       else
          create backup folder
          replace/copy source file to backup folder  
       replace source file
```

Comment: So....what have you tried?

Comment: I managed to do all of above without looping. Now I just need to put the logic inside a looping.

Comment: @Siva Ok, I made a mistake by coping the c# code in your answer into my script task. I thought it had something wrong because maybe different version. So I decided to rewrite it by myself and asked some questions while I am nailing it. Now I managed to make it work. The code looks similar to yours without the logging. I will add the logging. Anyway, it's a good exercise and makes me understand better. But still thank you a lot. I am going to close this.

Comment: @Siva. yeah, I found it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this methods:

- [Directory.GetDirectories()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.io.directory.getdirectories(v=vs.71).aspx)
- [File.Exists()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.io.file.exists%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
- [Directory.Exists()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.io.directory.exists%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
- [Directory.CreateDirectory()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.io.directory.createdirectory%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
- [File.Copy()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/c6cfw35a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

[As I told you before on the other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14976926/1967056), just check the methods on `System.IO`. Its very well documented on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.io%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), specially the classes [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.io.file(v=vs.80).aspx), [Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.io.directory(v=vs.80).aspx) and [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.io.path(v=vs.80).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

For getting subfolders refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003598/get-subdirectories) question

You then will want to put the sub folder locations into an array. From this array, loop through each object and so on.

Try using methods under 'File.' as this will include many functions for file processing. 
This will require the 'Imports System.IO'.